# Can you incorporate Github secrets in a custom configuration yml file?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions, github-secret

I have a python project where I intend to have a `.yml` config file. My question is, can something like this work in a github repo:

```yaml
name: something
  API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
name: somehting2
  SECRET_ID: ${{ secrets.SECRET_ID }}
```

This is not part of a github action, it's a config file in the root directory of the project. I prefer to have it this way rather than creating an environment variable for each credential and "pollute" the codebase with calls to get these variables.

Comment: Environment variables are a standard. Instead of polluting codebase you should have one file to resolve environment variables (i.e. environment.py) which would do all the work to resolve env vars or use defaults.

Comment: I understand. But you didn't answer my question

Comment: Oh, what you're proposing won't work, unless you do cat on the file inside your action yml to resolve which would be very weird imo.